# npm install is not working angular2

Tags: angular, npm-install

```js
tsconfig.jsonfile:

{
  "compilerOptions": {
    "target": "es5",
    "module": "commonjs",
    "moduleResolution": "node",
    "sourceMap": true,
    "emitDecoratorMetadata": true,
    "experimentalDecorators": true,
    "removeComments": false,
    "noImplicitAny": true,
    "suppressImplicitAnyIndexErrors": true
  }
}


npm-debug.log file
0 info it worked if it ends with ok
1 verbose cli [ 'node', '/usr/local/bin/npm', 'install' ]
2 info using npm@2.11.3
3 info using node@v0.12.7
4 verbose readDependencies loading dependencies from /Users/sxc103/Desktop/angular2/package.json
5 error install Couldn't read dependencies
6 verbose stack Error: ENOENT, open '/Users/sxc103/Desktop/angular2/package.json'
6 verbose stack     at Error (native)
7 verbose cwd /Users/sxc103/Desktop/angular2
8 error Darwin 15.2.0
9 error argv "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install"
10 error node v0.12.7
11 error npm  v2.11.3
12 error path /Users/sxc103/Desktop/angular2/package.json
13 error code ENOPACKAGEJSON
14 error errno -2
15 error package.json ENOENT, open '/Users/sxc103/Desktop/angular2/package.json'
15 error package.json This is most likely not a problem with npm itself.
15 error package.json npm can't find a package.json file in your current directory.
16 verbose exit [ -2, true ]
```

trying to play around with angular2 quick start. when I am running the npm install in the same folder its showing error:

> npm ERR! install Couldn't read dependencies

I have created the folder on the desktop.

Comment: Did you complete step 1.b (which is creating all of those files)?

Comment: You can refer sample package.json here - https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/quickstart.html#!#add-config-files

Answer (score 0):

It's **because** you don't have a **package.json** in your root directory. To **solve** this add a **package** json with dependencies configuration or try **npm init** to create a default **package.json** from **scratch**.